# Directional differences between $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf D$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

My confusion stems from the following exercise:

[image]

Since $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf D$ (electric displacement) are parallel (assuming we are dealing with a linear dielectric), and that given the picture on the left shows the field going into the rectangular shaped object from the bottom and out from the top, it looks like $\mathbf D_{in}$ points up along the way.

Since $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf D$ are assumed to be parallel, I don't see how this doesn't mean that $\mathbf E_{in}$ points up the way as well.

Comment: What is "D"?  Also, note - magnetic fields form closed loops ... electric fields do not form closed loops.

Comment: @DavidWhite Electric displacement, I'd say. That's a good point. Why is $\mathbf E$ being mentioned here then?

Comment: I don't know if I can answer your question, but I definitely can't answer without more context.  Also, your drawing's nomenclature probably conflicts with established nomenclature, which doesn't make the problem any easier to interpret.

Comment: Like you, I would say ${\bf E}={\bf D}/\varepsilon_0\varepsilon_r$ so answer A. Could you give us the beginning of the exercise and/or the reference to the book?

Comment: Unfortunately, this was all I was given, and it was not derivative of a textbook or anything as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I think the picture is fine for fields of permanently polarized dielectric. The left-hand part shows the field $\mathbf D$. The right-hand part shows the field $\mathbf E$, but only on the outside.

Answer (score 1):

On the picture we see lines of force of polarized bar of dielectric, with no external field. So this is *electret*, a body electrically polarized without presence of external field.

This is still an electrostatic situation, so electric lines of force cannot form loops of circulation; all lines start in positive charges (upper face) and end up in negative charges (bottom face). If the direction of electric field just outside the body is downwards, then inside this has to be downwards as well (from positive to negative pole).

On the other hand, displacement field $\mathbf D$ has zero divergence, it cannot originate in the polarization charges. It forms loops of circulation and this means inside the body, it points upwards (see the left-hand part of the picture). So inside the body, $\mathbf D$ has opposite direction to $\mathbf E$.

This is similar to magnetic fields inside a bar magnet, where $\mathbf B$ has opposite direction to $\mathbf H$.

Comment: That would look discontinuous and a bit 'unnatural' looking, as you'd expect the the lines to look as they do on the left -- although not by any physics-justified reasoning.

Few things:

Why can't electric lines of force form loops of circulation? Because the curl is $0$ in electrostatics?

Why is the divergence of $\mathbf D = 0$? 

Why do we know lines start in upper face, and end up on bottom face and not the other way around? Why do we know the upper face is positive and bottom face negative?

Comment: Electric field of static sources is given by the Coulomb formula. It is a potential field, it has zero curl everywhere, so no loops. Divergence of D at some point is zero if there is no free charge there, then field D is solenoidal with no sources. The left-hand part of the picture shows that is the case, D does not start anywhere, it forms closed loops, so no free charge is present. From the picture it is obvious that electric field lines of force come out of the upper face and sink into the bottom face - notice the arrows.